# JPA + Hibernate OGM + Lazy Initialization with Jackson Datatype Hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, jackson, lazy-initialization, hibernate-ogm

I want to choose when to load Set  with Lazy

This is my entity Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Type(type = "objectid")
   private String id;
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<Category> categories;
```

This is my AbstractService

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractService(Class<T> entityClass){
        this.entityClass=entityClass;

    public List<T> findAll(){
        Query nativeQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("{}", entityClass);
        return getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("{}",entityClass).getResultList();
    }
}
```

this i my ProductService

```
@Stateless
public class ProductService extends AbstractService<Product> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "name-db")
    private EntityManager em;

    public ProductService() {
        super(Product.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
```

this is my test method

```
    @Test
    public void testFindAllProducts()throws Exception {
       List<Product> products = productService.findAll();
        for (Product p:
            products ) {
            //Hibernate.initialize(p.getCategories());
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }
```

I would like to use a proxy to initialize the categories every time I need it

> Hibernate (including Hibernate OGM) supports lazy loading using proxy objects instead of
>   instances of the entity classes.
>   Hibernate uses proxies as a solution for “breaking up” the interconnected data received from a database into
>   smaller pieces that can be easily stored in memory. It may be useful to be aware that Hibernate dynamically generates
>   proxies for objects that are lazily loaded. Chances are, you aren’t aware of proxy objects, and won’t be until you get
>   some exceptions of type LazyInitializationException, or until you try to test lazy loading in a debugger and notice
>   the presence of some not-null objects with null properties. Not knowing when you’re “working” on a proxy object
>   instead of an entity object can cause weird results or exceptions

How can i implement a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement a proxy, Hibernate OGM will instantiate one as needed.

In this case, for each result the value returned by p.getCategories() should be a proxy.

Comment: In fact, but when I try to access I get it                                                  _Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role_

Comment: You should check that everything happens inside a running transaction. Hibernate OGM still requires transaction demarcation, even with MongoDB.